# Trying to connect Pegasus Raid 4TB to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

MBP does not see the Raid. I also have an iMac 27" connected to the Raid with a thunderbolt cable, works fine.

Comment: Are both connected at the same time?

Comment: Yes. There are 2 Thunderbolt ports on the Raid, one Thunderbolt cable goes directly from iMac to Raid, then I tried to connect Thunderbolt/ethernet cable, the ethernet going to my older MacBook Pro.

Comment: I did read that I might need a Thunderbolt 1.2 update, but when I downloaded it, I couldn't install on my operating system (I'm on 10.7.5, it required 10.8.xx).

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting the impossible. You can't connect two Macs to the same Thunderbolt chain. The two Thunderbolt ports on the Pegasus are so that you can daisychain devices, not Macs.

Second, the Pegasus you have doesn't talk Ethernet.

You could use the second port to attach a display or another disk device but not a Mac.

Since your MacBook Pro doesn't have a Thunderbolt port you can't connect it to the Pegasus directly. You could use a Thunderbolt to FireWire cable, but even then not at the same time as it was connected to the iMac.

Answer (score -1):

I would break things down and add one piece at a time.

- disconnect all cables and power on all devices
- pick one Mac and open System Information
- refresh the thunderbolt display to see nothing is connected
- connect only one thunderbolt cable to the RAID
- refresh the System Information thunderbolt pane - ensure the drive is seen
- eject the drive and disconnect the cable from the Mac
- plug the cable to the other Mac (having System Information ready to confirm it connects)

Without knowing which Pegasus RAID you have - it's hard to know how to troubleshoot the ethernet issue, but you could certainly ask a second question once you're convinced both Mac can see the RAID when only one connects. My suspicion is you can chain many drives to one mac, but not introduce a second Mac anywhere in the chain and have it participate with the storage unless it is in target disk mode itself *(in which case it will be just another drive in the chain)*.